# Check how many times smooth spline intersects with x-axis

Tags: r, intersection, spline

I want to check how many times my smoothed spline intersects with the x-axis. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Example: (1 intersection in this case)

[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/[![image.jpg]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8lfG.jpg))

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Exactly what type of R objects are you working with here?

Comment: do you mean intersect the y=0 line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the number of times `y` values go from positive to negative

```
set.seed(1571933401)
x = 1:100
y = rnorm(100)
sp = smooth.spline(x, y)

with(sp, sum((sign(c(0, y)) * sign(c(y, 0))) == -1))
#6

graphics.off()
plot(sp, type = "l")
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]